# Paypal IPN: get Buyer address

Tags: paypal

I have used the sandbox to get informations returned by Paypal IPN after a transaction.
The problem I have is that IPN doesn't send the buyer address information but I can still get his first name and his last name of the buyer for example.
I can get the transaction ID or item bought information without problem too. The only variables I can't get are all buyer address information like $_POST['address_name'] or $_POST['address_city'].
This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type='hidden' value="Montant_Achat" name="amount" />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR" />
<input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
<input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXX">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Durée"><span id="texteDuree">Durée : </span><select id="duree" onchange="changeCustom()" name="os0">

<option value="1 mois" id="30">1 mois €0,01 EUR</option>
<option value="3 mois" id="90">3 mois €15,00 EUR</option>
<option value="6 mois" id="180">6 mois €30,00 EUR</option>

</select>
</p>
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="factures.php" />
<input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="paypal_pro.php" />
<input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="paypal/paypal_notify.php" />

<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Nom de votre produit" />
<input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="FR" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
<input id="custom" name="custom" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["numUser"]; ?>||30" />

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />
<input type='hidden' name="address_override" value="1">
<input type="image" style="height:auto;" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/FR/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - la solution de paiement en ligne la plus simple et la plus sécurisée !">

<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</form>
```

This is the beggining of my paypal notify file:

```
// lire le formulaire provenant du système PayPal et ajouter 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// renvoyer au système PayPal pour validation
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
$_req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$_req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// récupération des informations de paypal
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = explode("||", $_POST['custom']);
$id_user = $custom[0];
$dureeContrat = $custom[1];



$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$address_city = $_POST["address_city"];
$address_country = $_POST["address_country"];
$address_country_code = $_POST["address_country_code"];
$address_name = $_POST["address_name"];
$address_state = $_POST["address_state"];
$address_street = $_POST["address_street"];
$address_zip = $_POST["address_zip"];
```

And this is the $POST variables returned by IPN:

```
Key: mc_gross

Key: protection_eligibility

Key: payer_id


Key: tax

Key: payment_date

Key: payment_status

Key: charset

Key: first_name

Key: option_selection1

Key: mc_fee

Key: notify_version

Key: custom

Key: payer_status

Key: business

Key: quantity

Key: verify_sign

Key: payer_email


Key: option_name1
Key: txn_id

Key: payment_type

Key: btn_id

Key: last_name

Key: receiver_email

Key: payment_fee

Key: shipping_discount

Key: insurance_amount

Key: receiver_id

Key: txn_type

Key: item_name


Key: discount
Key: mc_currency

Key: item_number

Key: residence_country

Key: handling_amount

Key: shipping_method

Key: transaction_subject

Key: payment_gross

Key: shipping

Key: ipn_track_id
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal will only send an address with the IPN notification if an address was included with the payment information.  Otherwise, it leaves it out entirely.

If during the button creation process you specified that shipping was not required that would cause no shipping to be returned in IPN.  Another possibility is that you don't have shipping required on the order so the buyer simply opts out of including their shipping address during checkout, in which case PayPal won't send it to you.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I had to add the shipping requirement option during the creation of the button.